# How to paste an R vector to sql query?

Tags: sql, r, database

I have a vector with values:

```
id = c("a1", "s44", "qq11", "f5")
```

I want to write the sql query and paste those values in it:

```
dbGetQuery(con, "SELECT * from my.table WHERE col1 in id")
```

As you see I want those values be after "in" in  query. How to paste it there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```r
id <-  c("a1", "s44", "qq11", "f5")
```

First you want to concatenate the elements of `id` with commas, so that it can be inserted into your SQL statement.

```r
sql_list_string <- paste(id, collapse = "', '")
sql_list_string
#> [1] "a1', 's44', 'qq11', 'f5"
```

Then, `paste()` it into your SQL statement.

```r
query <-
  paste0("SELECT * from my.table WHERE col1 in ('", sql_list_string, "')")
query
#> [1] "SELECT * from my.table WHERE col1 in ('a1', 's44', 'qq11', 'f5')"
```

You can now use query in your call to `dbGetQuery()` like this: `dbGetQuery(con, query)`

Comment: it brings ```SELECT * from my.table WHERE col1 in (a1, s44, qq11, f5)```, but must be ```SELECT * from my.table WHERE col1 in ('a1', 's44', 'qq11', 'f5')```

Answer (score 2):

You need to use dbGetQuery params argument.

```
    id = c("a1", "s44", "qq11", "f5")
    dbGetQuery(con, "SELECT * from my.table WHERE col1 in (?,?,?,?)",
    params=id)
```

You will need one `?` for each element of the vector. [dbGetQuery](https://rdrr.io/cran/DBI/man/dbGetQuery.html)

Comment: I suggest `paste(rep("?", length(id)), collapse=",")` for generating the parens, which you can use (wrapped in parens) to create the full query.

Answer (score 1):

Use sprintf like this.  It works with an arbitrary number of elements.  (If id contained numbers instead of character strings then the inner sprintf could be replaced with id as we would not need the single quotes surrounding each element.)

Note that dot is an SQL operator so my.table needs to be escaped (or choose a name not containing dot).

```
# inputs
id <-  c("a1", "s44", "qq11", "f5")
my.table <- data.frame(col1 = c("s44", "t44", "s44", "u44"), col2 = 1:4)

sql.template <- "SELECT * from [my.table] WHERE col1 in (%s)"
sql <- sprintf(sql.template, toString(sprintf("'%s'", id)))
sql
## [1] "SELECT * from [my.table] WHERE col1 in ('a1', 's44', 'qq11', 'f5')"
```

Test with the data frame defined above

```
library(RSQLite)

con <- dbConnect(SQLite())
dbWriteTable(con, "my.table", my.table)

dbGetQuery(con, sql)
##   col1 col2
## 1  s44    1
## 2  s44    3

dbDisconnect(con)
```